# Googlebot can't see data loaded from Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, googlebot, google-search-console

The new frontend of my website is based on the awesome Firebase friendlypix-web [demo](https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix-web) and deployed successfully to Firebase hosting.

The current site already gets its content from Firebase using the REST API with pages rendered on my server. The new all-js frontend gives users accounts and other interactive features.

But - and this is a big but - the Google Search Console URL Inspection tool (formerly "Fetch as Google") can't see the content loaded from Firebase. Only the page header is visible.

I thought Google did JavaScript... am I doing something wrong? Checking, it appears that content from the live demo https://friendly-pix.com is also not indexed by Google.

Have I just spent weeks developing this vastly superior version of my site for nothing? I can keep the old site synced and running... could I somehow use it to show Googlebot, with human users directed to the new site?

I'm not feeling too good about this...

Answer (score 1):

Googlebot does do JavaScript, however it queues it for rendering differently which causes the delays you're experiencing. You can find out more in this recent Webcast from Google Webmasters, skip to 8:21 in the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZtCgrpa6ss

Comment: Thanks for the video @Trickytree22. I didn't know about the deferred rendering. But how can I check on this rendering? Should I first request indexing of a page and then later check the search console again? 
Running a special pre-rendering server only for Googlebot is possible but not ideal!